# NDK Build for CoolReader

Tags: build, android-ndk

Im new to NDK, Installed cygwin and added to path folder too. From eclipse when tried to build by project contextmenu>build configuration>build selected got the below error in the console. What is **lvstring.h** . Im using windows 7, java 7, eclipse indigo

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project CoolReader ****

E:\exe\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build.cmd all 
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver

Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup

Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver

Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup

Gdbserver      : [mipsel-linux-android-4.6] libs/mips/gdbserver

Gdbsetup       : libs/mips/gdb.setup

Gdbserver      : [x86-4.6] libs/x86/gdbserver

Gdbsetup       : libs/x86/gdb.setup

"Compile++ thumb : cr3engine-3-1-0 <= cr3engine.cpp

In file included from jni/cr3engine.cpp:15:0:
jni/cr3java.h:18:22: fatal error: lvstring.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cr3engine-3-1-0/cr3engine.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: What is the name of project directory? Can you find file `crengine\include\lvstring.h` under the coolreader directory? Does your `Android.mk` file include line `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../crengine/include` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is fixed, seems to compile the native codes some lib from parent folder of project is required.

actually there are some lib files in repo which is not inside the project folder but outside it. so ndk build threw error, once it was changed it compiled by taking all dependency

Comment: "Looks ok" to me, since this is the OP reporting on his progress in getting the question answered. Yes, he could have provided more information on the solution, but I don't want to ding him for telling us the outcome.